# Numerical Solution for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, simulation

For a simulation in Python, I'd like to numerically solve a PDE of the following form:

$$
du(t,x) = \mu \partial_x u(t,x)dt + \sigma \partial_{xx} u(t,x) dt + \alpha \partial_x u(t,x) dw(t),\quad \text {with}\quad u_t(0)=0
$$

where $\alpha, \sigma, \mu$ are constant, and a Brownian path $w(t)$. The idea behind this is, that for every time change $\bigtriangleup t=t_{i+1}-t_{i}$, the change in $u(t,x)$ is $$\bigtriangleup t(\mu\partial_x u(t,x) + \sigma \partial_{xx} u(t,x)) + (\alpha \partial_x u(t,x))(w(t_{i+1})-w(t_i)).$$

My original approach was applying Fast Fourier Transformation, but I'm only able to get an approximation to the solution without the $w(t)$ part. How is it possible to transform this PDE to a nice form for numerical approximation?

Comment: This is now better, the formulas make sense syntactically. So the whole is a PDE with transport and dissipation and a space-uniform random perturbation. Please explore the problems with the FFT approach further. For an expansion $u(t,x)=\sum \hat u_k(t)e^{i ωkx}$ you should simply get $$d\hat u_k(t)=(iωkμ-ω^2k^2σ)\hat u_k\,dt+ iωkα\hat u_k(t)dw(t).$$ This could be somewhat unstable with the explicit Euler-Maruyama, so better use an implicit method or use the solution as geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: I like the suggestion! Would this mean, using the solution as geometric Brownian motion and applying inverse transformation, which should give me the result?

Comment: Yes, that should definitely work. Depending on where you are going, this will provide at least a nice test example.